# Agora.io : Having issue with acquire POST call REST API in cloud recording

Tags: node.js, agora.io

I am trying to set up cloud recording in Agora.io video call.According to agora [docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/restfulapi/#/Cloud%20Recording/acquire) first step is to call acquire API.
Initially I had issue with unescaped character is URL using axios NodeJS so I used `encodeURI` to bypass that error.My requests config is as follows

```
{
   "url":"https://api.agora.io%E2%80%8B/v1%E2%80%8B/apps%E2%80%8B/xxxxxxx_APPID_xxxx%E2%80%8B/cloud_recording%E2%80%8B/acquire",
   "method":"post",
   "data":"{\"cname\":\"5f30xxxx-xx33-xxa9-adxx-xxxxxxxx\",\"uid\":\"75\",\"clientRequest\":{\"resourceExpiredHour\":24}}",
   "headers":{
      "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization":"Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "User-Agent":"axios/0.19.2",
      "Content-Length":102
   },
   "transformRequest":[
      null
   ],
   "transformResponse":[
      null
   ],
   "timeout":0,
   "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
   "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
   "maxContentLength":-1
}
```

I get this response
`Error: Request failed with status code 400`

I have enabled cloud recording in agora console still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at the [Agora Postman Collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest), which helps provide properly formatted requests.

In your request you are missing the

For example your request should look like this:

```js
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({"cname":"demo","uid":"527841","clientRequest":{ "resourceExpiredHour": 24}});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/<xxxx_APPID_xxxx>/cloud_recording/acquire',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Here is a guide I've written for [getting started with the Postman Collection for Agora's Cloud Recording](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708).